# Pointer variable inside a function points to stack or heap?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

```
void foo (char *input) {
  char *myVar;
  *myVar = *input;
}
```

I understand that if I allocate `myVar` memory using `malloc(sizeof(char)` it will point to *heap*, but what if I don't allocate the memory, when I deference it, how the compiler handles the memory allocation? will it be allocated in *stack* or *heap*?

Comment: There is no memory allocation involved in dereferencing a pointer.  So your code simply exhibits *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: But there is a fine **undefined behavior** in assigning to a dereferenced *indeterminate* pointer in this snippet.

Comment: In your code `*myVar = *input;`  calls undefined behaviour, btw both `myVar`, `input` stores on stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I deference it, how the compiler handles the memory allocation

*Dereferencing* a pointer's value (an address) is not allocating memory. *Dereferencing* just gives you access to the memory the reference, that is the pointer points to.

From where this memory had been allocated (if ever) depends on what had been assigend to the pointer. ls.

Note: *Dereferencing* an uninitialised pointer provokes undefined behaviour, as it does for any read-accees to uninitialised memory/variables.

Comment: did you mean that in a typical embedded system it points to .BSS (uninitialized data section) ?

Comment: @Chen: It could point anywhere. In C there is **no** default initialisation besides for variables declared `static`, those default to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `myVar` is on the stack (for compilers which store local variables on the stack), but it doesn't point anywhere. That means when you dereference it you have *undefined behavior*.

Technically, the value of `myVar` will be indeterminate (i.e. seemingly random) so it will point to a random location. This means that the dereference may *sometimes* cause a crash, while other times it may not.

Comment: I wouldn't call it random. Then someone comes along and wants to use unallocated memory as a PRNG... (don't find the question, but there is one such...)

Comment: @glglgl: You mean like the infamous [Debian OpenSSL implementation](http://msmvps.com/blogs/alunj/archive/2008/05/15/1623193.aspx)?

Comment: @glglgl That's why I said *seemingly* random.